# Kamon with spring and akka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, akka, kamon

I'm using `akka` (java) in combination with `spring boot`. I would like to monitor metrics with `kamon` and show them on a `grafana` dashboard. I've included `kamon core` `kamon statsd` to the dependencies and created an `application.conf` with the correct port and hostname for `statsd`. There are no clear examples or tutorials that show the stack i'm using. Is it possible to measure the `akka` metrics using `spring boo`t, `java`, `akka` and `kamon` deployed as war in `tomcat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a simple example

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>kamon.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>kamon-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
        <artifactId>kamon-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
        <artifactId>kamon-annotation_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
        <artifactId>kamon-akka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
        <artifactId>kamon-log-reporter_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>io.kamon</id>
        <url>http://snapshots.kamon.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

two actors to play a ping pong game

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

class Pinger extends UntypedActor {
 static final class PingMessage {}

 public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if (message instanceof Ponger.PongMessage) getSender().tell(new PingMessage(), getSelf());
    else unhandled(message);
}
```

}

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

class Ponger extends UntypedActor {
 static final class PongMessage {}

 public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if (message instanceof Pinger.PingMessage) getSender().tell(new PongMessage(), getSelf());
    else unhandled(message);
 }
```

}

a spring component

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class PingPong {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("kamon-spring-boot-actor-system");

        final ActorRef pinger = system.actorOf(Props.create(Pinger.class), "pinger");
        final ActorRef ponger = system.actorOf(Props.create(Ponger.class), "ponger");

        pinger.tell(new Ponger.PongMessage(), ponger);
    }
}
```

also make a simple controller in order to show how simple is using the [kamon-annotation](http://kamon.io/integrations/annotation/using-annotations/) module to gather some other metrics

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/kamon")
@EnableKamon
public class KamonController {

  @RequestMapping("/counter")
  @ResponseBody
  @Count(name = "awesomeCounter")
  public String counter() {  return "count!!!"; }
}
```

the application main

```
import kamon.akka.pingpong.PingPong;
import kamon.annotation.KamonController;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

public class KamonSpringApplication {
  public static void main(String... args) {
   Kamon.start();
   SpringApplication.run(KamonController.class, args);
  }
}
```

application.conf simplified for testing purposes

```
kamon {
  metric {
    filters {
      trace.includes = [ "**" ]
      akka-actor.includes = [ "**" ]
      akka-actor.excludes = ["*/system/**", "*/user/IO-**" ]
      akka-dispatcher.includes = [ "**" ]
      akka-dispatcher.excludes = [ ]
    }
  }
 }
```

build the application and run

```
mvn package && java -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar -jar target/kamon-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
```

should we get something like this

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                  |
|    Actor: kamon-spring-boot-actor-system/user/pinger                                             |
|                                                                                                  |
|   Processing Time (nanoseconds)      Time in Mailbox (nanoseconds)         Mailbox Size          |
|    Msg Count: 3393358                    Msg Count: 3393405                  Min: 0              |
|          Min: 237                              Min: 178                     Avg.: 0.0            |
|    50th Perc: 672                        50th Perc: 756                      Max: 2              |
|    90th Perc: 988                        90th Perc: 1264                                         |
|    95th Perc: 1088                       95th Perc: 1368                                         |
|    99th Perc: 1520                       99th Perc: 1848                   Error Count: 0        |
|  99.9th Perc: 20480                    99.9th Perc: 17920                                        |
|          Max: 16646144                         Max: 34865152                                     |
|                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                  |
|    Actor: kamon-spring-boot-actor-system/user/ponger                                             |
|                                                                                                  |
|   Processing Time (nanoseconds)      Time in Mailbox (nanoseconds)         Mailbox Size          |
|    Msg Count: 3739208                    Msg Count: 3739161                  Min: 0              |
|          Min: 272                              Min: 172                     Avg.: 0.0            |
|    50th Perc: 672                        50th Perc: 732                      Max: 2              |
|    90th Perc: 976                        90th Perc: 1232                                         |
|    95th Perc: 1064                       95th Perc: 1344                                         |
|    99th Perc: 1360                       99th Perc: 1656                   Error Count: 0        |
|  99.9th Perc: 10496                    99.9th Perc: 14272                                        |
|          Max: 7766016                          Max: 30277632                                     |
|                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and if we do 2 curls

```
http://localhost:8080/kamon/counter
http://localhost:8080/kamon/counter

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                  |
|                                         Counters                                                 |
|                                       -------------                                              |
|                             awesomeCounter  =>  2                                                |
|                                                                                                  |
|                                                                                                  |
|                                        Histograms                                                |
|                                      --------------                                              |
|                                                                                                  |
|                                      MinMaxCounters                                              |
|                                    -----------------                                             |
|                                                                                                  |
|                                          Gauges                                                  |
|                                        ----------                                                |
|                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[link](https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/tree/master/kamon-examples/kamon-annotation-example/java) to the complete example.

Hope this can help you.